# how can I extract drupal-x.x.tar.gz file

Tags: php, linux, drupal-7

I was download the the **drupal-x.x.tar.gz** on my machine.
and trying to extract using following command provide by drupal

```
$ tar -xzvf drupal-x.x.tar.gz   
$ tar -xf drupal-x.x.tar.gz
```

but It's not working, It's give following error.

> **tar: Unrecognized archive format**
>   **tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.**

How can I extract this file?

Comment: The file got corrupted during transfer. You should redownload the file.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a short answer, but I normally use the following without issue:

```
$ tar -xvf drupal-x.x.tar.gz
```

If this doesn't work I would suggest:

```
gunzip drupal-x.x.tar.gz
tar -xvf drupal-x.x.tar.gz
```

Another thing I would mention is if you have downloaded this via a `wget` command, test the URL in the browser, often the link has a bunch of `GET` parameters that need to be removed first from the link url. For example, I recently copied a link like so:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/dw-rs/bin/2.2/RS2.2.1-5602-reportserver-x64-bundle.exe?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fdw-rs%2F&ts=1423660433&use_mirror=softlayer-ams

In order to use `wget` I had to modify it like so:

http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/dw-rs/bin/2.2/RS2.2.1-5602-reportserver-x64-bundle.exe

I have tested using the following commands and it is working for me:

```
wget http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.34.tar.gz
tar -xvf drupal-7.34.tar.gz
```

I would suggest reissuing the commands and deleting the original downloaded file.

Comment: $gunzip drupal-x.x.tar.gz It's give error like                                            **gunzip: drupal-x.x.tar.gz: not in gzip format**

Comment: @SwapnilPatil please see my updated answer with a working solution

Comment: @SwapnilPatil If this solved your issue, please tick the answer. Glad I could help.